# both headlights, beam, dashboard etc not coming on

Tags: ignition, lights

Car is a civic vti coupe 1999.

Both headlights and the beam lights are not coming on.  when you turn the headlights on the dashboard usually lights up simultaneously with the headlight so you can see the speedometer in the dark etc.  However this is not coming on either.  Other electronics are working, car does start and drive.

I believe I checked the fuses for both headlights and they are ok.

What is is likely cause\what things should I look into?

Note that these problems have come after we were trying to replace an ignition switch but eventually didnt replace it as we couldn't get an immobiliser related wire out of the old ignition switch socket.  Mechanic really struggled with that and even took the white plastic bit out of the socket.  if you look at the picture you can see I have pointed to a white box which is located inside the socket.  he physically removed this and said dont worry you don't need it. it was just plastic but just mentioning.  Is he right I imagine the white plastic inside the socket served some purpose?
Note that the pic is the new switch so does not have the immobiliser related wire coming out of the socket. Anyway just mentioned this because lights were working fine when I originally removed and put switch back, however after mechanic did the above the listed lights have gone. All other electronics are fine and car starts and drives.[image]

Comment: Year/make/model?  I think I would troubleshoot the lights the old fashion way, with a wiring diagram, rather than speculate about damage to the ignition switch harness.

Comment: Prior to this would the headlights/highbeams work if the ignition was "off"? Also does the car currently start and drive?

Comment: @motosubatsu I imagine so since if I remember right these lights come on with the first or second clicks of key turning though I cant remember.  They were definitively working though before ignition switch work.  Yes car starts and drives.